# Formatting MySQL results as currency

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-function

What will be the best way to include the result with dollar sign?

I was using something like `CONCAT('£', SUM(Deposits)) AS TotalDeposits` but it seems not working.

[image]

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to do that. Formatting (such as adding currency symbols) should be something you do in the UI where you display the data, not in the raw query

Comment: Short answer: Don't. Format numbers with currency in your application layer. MySQL has zero clue as to how to format numbers properly for currencies where `$x,xxx.xx`, `($x,xxx.xx)`, `$x xxx,xx` and `xx,xx$` are how some locales deal with it. Things get even stranger from there, so forget about trying to figure this out. Find a localization library that can deal with it, learn how to use it, and let the user decide how they want it.

Comment: If you want to use a dollar sign, why does your code have a pound sign?

Comment: "but it seems not working" will not help us help you.  What makes it "not working"?  What is "not working"?  No result???  Wrong result???  Error out???

Answer (score 10):

MySQL boasts a [FORMAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) for doing the number formatting part of this.

```
SET @amount := 123456.7890;
SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(@amount,2,'en_US')),
       CONCAT('€',FORMAT(@amount,2,'de_DE'));
```

gets you the US and DE formatting. You have to put in the currency symbol yourself; MySQL's locale handling doesn't throw it in for you.

```
| ------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------- |
| $123,456.79                           | €123.456,79                           |
| ------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------- |
```

If you're dealing with other peoples' money, you may want to use a data type like `DECIMAL(20,2)` rather than a `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` so you don't get floating-point-style arithmetic rounding errors in aggregate functions like `SUM()`.

That all being said: wise programmers often handle this kind of formatting in their application programs rather than their databases, as @ADyson pointed out in his comment. That's because application programming languages have more complete locale handling than databases (at any rate MySQL) and you can control it better.